# ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session. session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I'm getting an error 'ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83' while running a script in WebdriverIO V6 with Cucumber framework though I'm running in chrome browser (85.0.4183.83) locally and my chromedriver configuration in package.json file is "chromedriver": "^85.0.0".

The only concern here is even If I keep my chromedriver version 85.exe file in my node_modules->.selenium-> chromedriver then It's throwing a same error while running a script.

Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to either set chromedriver version in the selenium standalone config https://webdriver.io/docs/selenium-standalone-service.html#configuration or use https://webdriver.io/docs/docs/wdio-chromedriver-service.html only but not all together.

chromedriver package is not used by selenium-standalone-service

Note: please use chromedriver (not Chrome browser!) version, see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads